# Can not render image from S3 bucket in WebGL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, webgl

When my JavaScript app trys to load an image from my Amazon S3 account and render it in WebGL the browser throws a CORS error. I changed the S3 bucket's CORS configuration to allow access:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Unfortunately, browsers still throw the CORS error when I try to render an image from the S3 bucket.

Is there a step I missed? Or, is this just normal? In other words, does WebGL always reject cross-domain files regardless of whether the file's domain allows access via the appropriate CORS configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/)

> In order to load it with CORS as a WebGL texture, we set the crossOrigin attribute on it:

```
var earthImage = new Image();
earthImage.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

> Now we load it as usual:

```
earthImage.onload = function() {
  // whatever you usually to do load WebGL textures
};
earthImage.src = "http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=95&x=0&y=0&z=0";
```

Comment: Thanks, Gman. I'm marking this as answered since your answer is apparently correct and works for Firefox. Unfortunately, it does not work for Chrome or IE. I'm guessing those browsers simply don't yet support the "crossOrigin" attribute.  :-(

Comment: try setting it like `earthImage.crossOrigin = "";`  Chrome was the first to support cors for WebGL so it should work.

Comment: `earthImage.crossOrigin = "";` didn't work either. AWS CORS docs state AWS won't add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response unless the request includes an origin header. So, maybe Chrome and IE do not include the origin header.